# How to obtain the virtual private memory of a process from the command line under OSX?

Tags: macos, memory, command-line

I would like to obtain the virtual private memory consumed by a process under OSX from the command line. This is the value that Activity Monitor reports in the "Virtual Mem" column. `ps -o vsz` reports the total address space available to the process and is therefore not useful.

Comment: For parsing or viewing? top/htop is a great viewer.

Comment: I need it for parsing. I want to record how memory consumption develops over several stages of the program run and do so across various program versions and problem parameters. Therefore, I need to be able to collect data from a script.

Comment: Ok, trying to learn how to comment on stackoverflow, so here the previous comment continued: I need it for parsing. I want to record how memory consumption develops over several stages of the program run and do so across various program versions and problem parameters. Therefore, I need to be able to collect data from a script.  After looking more closely at the top documentation, running `top -l 1 -s 0 -i 1 -stats vprvt -pid PID` and parsing just the last line of the output seems to give the required information, if only in whole MBs (top does not seem to let the user choose units).

Comment: Hi @user1389686: If you click on [Answer your own question] and paste the above comment as the answer, then you'll be able accept your own answer.  Then it will be easier for people to find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the virtual private memory use of a single process by running

```
top -l 1 -s 0 -i 1 -stats vprvt -pid PID
```

where `PID` is the process ID of the process you are interested in. This results in about a dozen lines of output ending with

```
VPRVT
55M+
```

So by parsing the last line of output, one can at least obtain the memory footprint in MB. I tested this on OSX 10.6.8.

Comment: If I try this in Yosemite, I get `VPRVT 
N/A`

Answer (score 0):

#### update

I realized (after I got downvoted) that @user1389686 gave an answer in the comment section of the OP that was better than my paltry first attempt.  What follows is based on user1389686's own answer.  I cannot take credit for it -- I've just cleaned it up a bit.

#### original, edited with -stats vprvt

As Mahmoud Al-Qudsi mentioned, `top` does what you want.  If PID 8631 is the process you want to examine:

```
$ top -l 1 -s 0 -stats vprvt -pid 8631
Processes: 84 total, 2 running, 82 sleeping, 378 threads 
2012/07/14 02:42:05
Load Avg: 0.34, 0.15, 0.04 
CPU usage: 15.38% user, 30.76% sys, 53.84% idle 
SharedLibs: 4668K resident, 4220K data, 0B linkedit.
MemRegions: 15160 total, 961M resident, 25M private, 520M shared.
PhysMem: 917M wired, 1207M active, 276M inactive, 2400M used, 5790M free.
VM: 171G vsize, 1039M framework vsize, 1523860(0) pageins, 811163(0) pageouts.
Networks: packets: 431147/140M in, 261381/59M out.
Disks: 487900/8547M read, 2784975/40G written.

VPRVT
8631
```

Here's how I get at this value using a bit of Ruby code:

```
# Return the virtual memory size of the current process
def virtual_private_memory
  s = `top -l 1 -s 0 -stats vprvt -pid #{Process.pid}`.split($/).last
  return nil unless s =~ /\A(\d*)([KMG])/
  $1.to_i * case $2
            when "K" 
              1000
            when "M" 
              1000000
            when "G" 
              1000000000
            else
              raise ArgumentError.new("unrecognized multiplier in #{f}")
            end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer, thats work under Yosemite, from user1389686:

```
top -l 1 -s 0 -stats mem -pid PID
```